# Logging calls from Outlook (Lightning for Outlook)

Tags: outlook, lightning-outlook, lightning-for-outlook

According to Salesforce support, it isn't possible to add the "log a call" action to Lightning for Outlook (now branded "Outlook Integration").  This posts references the same:

[How can I 'Log A Call' using the Salesforce for Outlook sidebar](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p7JMQAY)

Anyone have a work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently found a solution for this.

Can't use default "Log a Call" action type, have to make a new custom "Log a Call" global action using a Create a Record action type mimicking the default log a call.

Target object: Task

Predefine "Task Subtype" to be "Call" to simulate default Log a Call

Predefine fields "Due Date -> TODAY()" and "Status -> Completed" to further simulate log a call.

Add this new action to publisher layout in Outlook Integration